# Foursquare API: Search venues in whole city

Tags: foursquare

Is it possible to search venues (via venues/search) in whole city without passing "radius" parameter? Because I don't know radius of each city :) Documentation says "Searches can be done near a point or through a whole city", but how can I provide this in venues/search?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

I do not think there is a way to tell it 'search the entire city', but I also think it might be a wrong use case.

You need to remember a few things when searching:

1. Foursquare will return up to 50 results (the limit parameter)
2. The 50 results are ordered by the most popular places around the center of your search

So if you are searching a city which have more than 50 venues in Foursquare database, 'searching the entire city' will usually get the same (up to) 50 results - always.

This where the filters comes in handy, in our case, to get you better results for our needs, we use the categoryId combined with the radius to get things we want to show our users. Sometimes we get information from other cities because of a big radius, but for our application its okay, we actually give our customers more options :) . I can also guess that a lot of apps also use the query filter as they know the name of the place they are looking for.

You just need to experiment with it and discover how to get the data which is right to your application.

In theory, to search an entire city I would use the city lat/lng from Google or Open Street Maps or geonames and do a 10Km search around that point (intent=browse, radius=10000), the following is a guess, but it will get 50 places for over 99% of the cities people who own smartphones live in :)

Answer (score 3):

You can do obtain results within in a city as follows:

```
https://api.foursquare.com/v2/venues/search?near=Singapore,Singapore&client_id=YOUR_CLIENT_ID
&client_secret=YOUR_CLIENT_SECRET3&v=YYYYMMDD
```

For more details check the documentation:

```
https://developer.foursquare.com/docs/venues/explore
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're talking about requests with a query, I would just set a reasonable value for radius and use the city's default city center. If you want to avoid showing results from neighboring cities, you can post-request filter by the returned venue's "city" string in the location stanza.